# syntax or logic error in mysql update

Tags: mysql

I have a list with the ids

1,2,3,4,5,6

and I drag and drop that so that 5 (self) goes between 1 and 2(next)
1,5,2,3,4,6

so I need 5 tobe 2(next)-1 and everything < 2(next) --> id=id-1 and everything > 5(self) --> id=id-1

so I wrote the sql

```
$sql = "UPDATE w3school SET id= CASE
                                     WHEN ".$self." > ".$next."  THEN id-1 
                                     END
                                     WHERE id < ".$next." AND id > ".$self.";";


$sql .="UPDATE w3school SET id= ".$next." - 1    WHERE id = ".$self."";
```

and I get:
0012346
so it just changed the 5 to 0;

THE PROBLEM IS WITH THE AND OF THE WHERE STATEMENT
not sure what's wrong there but seperately the staments work together not

Comment: You should never change IDs in the first place.

Comment: and how is the database position changed then and later implemented by the html elements?

Comment: what are the properties of the id field? Is it supposed to be unique?

Comment: just int nothing else

Comment: For a position of a record in a dataset you would have a column like `position` or `pos` or `sortkey` or the like, but not `id`. With a column named ID one always expect it to be the records unique ID.

Comment: I do change the elements id to, so the html position is reflecting the database, seems there like my point is not answered though

Comment: We are in 2017. Whatever language you are using (PHP I presume), stop crafting SQL with string concatenation and use prepared statements.

Comment: I've posted an answer right now. I am just saying that an **ID** is supposed to identify a record. Other related tables would reference this ID, e.g. a product ID may be used in an order table, so we know that the order contains that product. We would never want to change the order ID and have to change it in all other tables to stay consistent. An ID never changes. If you want some position like a position (line) in an order, then store a position and *call it* position or the like.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query we want:

```
update w3school
set id = case 
           when id = 5 then 2 -- change position
           when 5 > 2 then i + 1 -- if we move "this" left, then all ids go one place to the right
           else id - 1 -- and vice versa
         end
where (id >= 2 or id >= 5) -- lower ids than the two in question are irrelevant here
and 2 <> 5; -- if self = next nothing needs be done
```

As a string:

```
$sql = 
  " update w3school ".
  " set id = case ".
  "            when id = ".$self." then ".$next." ".
  "            when ".$self." > ".$next." then i + 1 ".
  "            else id - 1 ".
  "          end ".
  "where (id >= ".$next." or id >= ".$self.") and ".$next." <> ".$self.";";
```

Comment: mercie. ich habe den code benutzt, aber wenn ich mein element verschiebe aktualiert der den code und alles ist wie vorher. er setzt wieder alles zurück. woran kann das liegen?

Comment: sry. I dont know why I switched to german. the code runs, but its reset, so there is no effect of the change. why could that be?

Comment: Maybe you are missing a `COMMIT;` to confirm the changes?

Comment: where would the commit be?

Comment: There should be a command, something like `$db->commit();` you would send to the database after sending the update statement.

Answer (score 0):

the sql way would have been:

```
$sql   = "UPDATE w3school SET id= 1000   WHERE id = ".$self.";";
$sql  .= "UPDATE w3school SET id= id + 1 WHERE id < ".$self." AND id  >=  ".$next.";";
$sql  .= "UPDATE w3school SET id= ".$next." WHERE id = 1000";
```

I'm pretty sure @Thorsten Kttner was right too. However, I am new to his style, which might well be the normal one, so his answer would have been harder to implement for me.The 1000 is a little sloppy, but the logic and syntax was the question and are answered. The 1000 can easily be changed.